# Is it Possible to Sacrifice a Sacrificed Creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The title is confusing, I know. Here's the scenario: I sacrifice two creatures with Whisper, Blood Liturgist, can I then, in response to the creatures becoming sacrifice targets, sacrifice one of those same creatures using Hell's Caretaker and have both abilities still resolve correctly? I would think I would be able to because Whisper's ability is already on the stack when I activate Hell's Caretaker, but I'm not positive.